# include PySerial library in kivy distribution

Tags: android, python, serial-port, kivy, pyserial

I am working on a small python script which will run on Android using kivy. Basically I am new to Python programming.
The script itself works on my Computer under Linux, but I can't get the PySerial library compiled for android. 
I tried it with buildozer which debugs the app but it crashes on Android when I open it. 
Building the apk with python for android gets me following error

```
Run pymodules install
We want to install: serial
Check if and /usr/bin/pip2 are present
Check if virtualenv is existing
Installing virtualenv
./distribute.sh: line 119: --python=python2.7: command not found
```

Is there a way of including the serial library so it can be used on Android?

EDIT

error log:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /data/data/org.led.serialled/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-08-25_10.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] Factory: 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] Cache: register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] Cache: register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] Cache: register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/data/org.led.serialled/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:12: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG             ] Cache: register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] Cache: register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/konstantin/Desktop/buildozer_LED/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/konstantin/Desktop/buildozer_LED/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/serial/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/konstantin/Desktop/buildozer_LED/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/serial/serialposix.py", line 15, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr: ImportError: No module named termios
```

Comment: From the error log, looks like pyserial depends on termios, but that was not included in the build. Try adding termios to the requirements. Be carefull that it is not a pure python lib though

Answer (score 1):

This stands for any library, if it's a pure python lib or has a known [recipe](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes) then just add it in the requirements section of bulldozer.spec.

```
# requirements of the app
requirements = pyserial,pycrypto,pyasn1,pyjnius,twisted,kivy
```

However if the lib is not pure python you need to provide a [recipe](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/recipe.sh.tmpl) if it does not already exist [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes) which is nothing but a simple script that adds patches to the lib for compiling it for arm android. Then add it as a requirement to the bulldozer.spec.

pyserial seems like it's a pure python lib

Comment: thats what i did, but when I open the app on my android device, it instantly crashes after showing the splashscreen. when I don't include the pyserial in the requirements then it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

You have add `pyserial` to the requirements as mentioned and remove termios from the blacklist.

In your `buildozer.spec` use:

```
# (list) python-for-android whitelist
android.p4a_whitelist = lib-dynload/termios.so
```

or add `lib-dynload/termios.so` to whitelist.txt for the bootstrap being used (see 
   https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build/whitelist.txt)